# BottomSheetDialogFragment setupDialog restricted to library group

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I'm using [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html) from the support library and it warns me that the function `setupDialog()` should only be used within the library group. But this function is the place where I initialize my dialog:

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    FragmentArgs.inject(this);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(dialogINterface -> {
        if(dialog.getWindow() != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }
    });

    BottomSheetStatisticsExportBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),
            R.layout.bottom_sheet_statistics_export,
            null,
            false
    );

    View contentView = binding.getRoot();
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if( behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior )
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetBehaviorCallback);

    for (Export export : exports)
        binding.flexbox.addView(new ExportItemView(getContext(), export));
}
```

The warning is because I'm using the super method. But what should I do instead? Should I move my code inside another function (`onCreateDialog()`, `onResume()`...?), should I remove the call to the super?

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I move my code inside another function (onCreateDialog(),
>   onResume()...?)

Yes. As it demonstrates in the [`DialogFragment` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) (which `BottomSheetDialogFragment` extends), you should use `onCreateView()` to set up your dialog.

The `View` you return from this method will be set as the content view for the dialog provided by `onCreateDialog()`. And the `getDialog()` method can be used from within `onCreateView()` to make any adjustments to the aforementioned `Dialog`.

---

`onCreateDialog()` would be used to replace the default `Dialog`. Which in your case you probably don't want to do; considering that is the method `BottomSheetDialogFragment` uses to replace the default `Dialog` with a `BottomSheetDialog` (in fact, it is the only method `BottomSheetDialogFragment` overrides).

---

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bfarrelladelphi/e9f36bb5e1fd60f11fc6464a510499e5) are the `BottomSheetDialog` and `BottomSheetDialogFragment` classes I created to replace the support library versions (see comments for more information).

Comment: How do i implement 'BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback' ? Many examples override setupDialog(). @Bryan in your provided solution i am getting behaviour as null.

Comment: @Debjit Yeah, I had a lot of trouble with this. I find it very strange that the design library implementation gets the behavior, but doesn't expose it to subclasses. I actually ended up recreating the `BottomSheetDialog` class (I basically copy/pasted the code) and exposed the behavior from the `wrapInBottomSheet` method. I don't think it's the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: @Debjit After which, I also ended up recreating the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` class as well; using my version of the `BottomSheetDialog` instead of the design library version.